# Convert Class Object to Human Readable String

Tags: java, string

Is there any way in which I can **automatically** convert a Custom Class Object into a human readable string?

e.g. consider the following class:

```
class Person {
    String Name;
    int Salary;
    ...
}

Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Tony");
p.setSalary(1000);
```

I need to get something like:

```
Person: Name="Tony", Salary=1000
```

Comment: write a reflect utility to print all it's fields ?

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm looking for. But since using reflection gonna make it quite general, I was wondering if there is one already available somewhere!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Importing [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) you could use [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html)

Check method `reflectionToString(java.lang.Object)`, this will create automatically the representation you are expecting.

This code:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Tony");
p.setSalary(1000);

System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(p));
```

results this string:

```
Person@64578ceb[Name=Tony,Salary=1000]
```

Answer (score 3):

sure you can override the `toString` method of class.

as follow:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int salary;
    ...
    @Override public String toString() {
      return "Person: Name='" + name + "', Salary=" + salary;
    }
}
```

refer for more details https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/writing_tostring_methods_tech_days

Comment: you mean `p.toString();` ??? or just simply print `p` java will automatically invoke toString on it to print it.

Comment: ya that will print the object as a string.

Comment: you can also call it by directly object just simply p will also fine if you want to specify explicitly then also you can..

Answer (score 3):

This is basically what `toString` is for. But given you want this done automatically, you can create some general service that can do it. Use reflection to iterate all fields, and then print each one's name and value. Simplest way to print their values would be by using their `toString`, but you can also pass them into that printing service recursively on some cases (you'll have to find the halt condition, of course).

For example, on some class PrintUtils have:

```
public static void printFields(Object o) {
    System.out.print(o.getClass.getSimpleName() + ": ");
    for (Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);     // you also get non-public fields
        System.out.print(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(o) + ", ");
    }
}
```

You'll have to handle exceptions etc. and possibly better format the output, of course. Also, this only print fields declared in the current class. If you want fields declared higher in the inheritance hierarchy, you'll have to work a bit more. Lastly, using reflection is much slower than just having a regular `toString`. If using `toString` is possible, it is preferable.

Comment: Depending on his requirements, he might just rely on public getters. That would simplify the logic, only requiring him to iterate over `getMethods`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, yeah, sure. I only demonstrate the possibility, actual implementation should match the specific requirements.

Comment: No contention, just an addition :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) that is part of [`commons-lang`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to rely on Apache Commons [BeanUtils.describe](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/index.html). This will produce a `Map` of bean's properties, which converts to a string nicely via `Map.toString`. If you want something more custom, you'll need to dig into the reflection API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message format from java :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n//message.html
seperate variable by - and there you have a humanreadable string of your class!

Answer (score -1):

```
class Person {
    String Name;
    int Salary;
    ...

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return "Person: Name = " + Name + "," +
             "Salary="+Salary;
   }
}

Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Tony");
p.setSalary(1000);
System.out.println(p.toString());
```